# How to replace special characters and numbers with the character and spaces on each side

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

So basically I'm trying to convert this string: "(1+2) / 2" to this "( 1 + 2 ) / 2".
And I've tried this:

`String inputInfix = input.replaceAll("[^0-9/]", " [^0-9/] ");`

But it doesn't work, is there some way to replace every character except "/" and the digits with a space on either side. For example, "(1 / 2)" -> " ( 1 / 2 )"

Comment: You probably want `input.replaceAll("(?<=\\S)(?=\\S)", " ")`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/khfGv4/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! It almost works, but I also don't want to add any spaces to "/" so "(1/2+1/2)" should return "( 1/2 + 1/2 )"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  can use

```java
input.replaceAll("(?<=[^\\s/])(?=[^\\s/])", " ")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/khfGv4/2). *Details*:

- `(?<=[^\s/])` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with a char other than a whitespace char and a slash
- `(?=[^\s/])` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with a char other than a whitespace char and a slash.